# Trying to send ERC20 token with Javascript button without success

Tags: web3js, erc-20, metamask

I am trying to send an ERC20 token with the following code via web3.js. It was working until a week ago and then it stopped. Am I doing something wrong? Upon clicking it no longer interacts with Metamask. Thanks in advance for the help. Moses.

```
<script>
    window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    // Check if Web3 has been injected by the browser:
    if (typeof web3 !== 'undefined') {
        // You have a web3 browser! Continue below!
        startApp(web3);
        //alert("Web3");
    } else {
        //alert("No hay web3");
    }
})
const abi = [{
    "constant": false,
    "inputs": [
        {
            "name": "_to",
            "type": "address"
        },
        {
            "name": "_value",
            "type": "uint256"
        }
    ],
    "name": "transfer",
    "outputs": [
        {
            "name": "success",
            "type": "bool"
        }
    ],
    "payable": false,
    "type": "function"
}]
const contract_address = '0x89d24A6b4CcB1B6fAA2625fE562bDD9a23260359'
const etherValue = web3.toWei(10, 'ether');
var addr = '0xd7B9A9b2F665849C4071Ad5af77d8c76aa30fb32'
var amount = '200'
function startApp(web3) {
    //alert("entro");
    const eth = new Eth(web3.currentProvider)
    const token = eth.contract(abi).at(contract_address);
    listenForClicks(token,web3)
}
function listenForClicks (miniToken, web3) {
    var button = document.querySelector('button.transfer')
    web3.eth.getAccounts(function(err, accounts) { console.log(accounts); address = accounts.toString(); })
    button.addEventListener('click', function() {
        miniToken.transfer(addr, amount, { from: address })
            .then(function (txHash) {
            console.log('Transaction sent')
            console.dir(txHash)
            waitForTxToBeMined(txHash)
        })
            .catch(console.error)
    })
}
async function waitForTxToBeMined (txHash) {
    let txReceipt
    while (!txReceipt) {
        try {
            txReceipt = await eth.getTransactionReceipt(txHash)
        } catch (err) {
            return indicateFailure(err)
        }
    }
    indicateSuccess()
}
</script>
<br>
<button class="transfer">Send 200 tokens!</button>
</center>
```

edited: Edited to fix typo

Comment: see this https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/70623/not-accessing-metamask-address-through-web3-eth-getcoinbase/70624#70624

Comment: Hello, I do not understand what Privacy mode has to do with this?

Comment: The privacy mode in metamask "block" your  request, you can deactivate it or change to ask for permission first